# How detailed should I be when describing what material was covered in prereqs on a masters application?

Tags: graduate-admissions

I am applying to a good quantitative program and they have a section where they want me to list what textbooks I used and what material was covered in certain prereqs for the program.  How detailed should I be with these?  Right now I have the name of the book and every chapter heading that we covered.  I also have topics listed from supplementary slides and more advanced versions of the same courses that I'm taking now listed underneath them along with those topics.

Is that too much?

Comment: What exactly did they ask for?

Comment: * Describe the calculus based probability course you've taken (include the textbook name and topics covered)

* Describe the calculus based mathematical statistics course you've taken (include the textbookand topics covered)

* Describe the regression analysis course you've taken (include the textbook name and topics covered)

Comment: It sounds like the information you have is just what they asked for.

Comment: I am voting to close as non-generalizable because I believe this question was answered in comments, and the answer boils down to: "follow the particular application instructions given by the particular program"

Answer (score 1):

The forms probably have some space reserved for this, that should give you a fair idea of how much you are supposed to write. In any case, concentrate on the final courses of the relevant line(s), don't list everything from freshman up.

Comment: It was an online form and I ended up being very detailed about the specific courses they asked about.  Not sure if that was a good idea, but I got in!